# Accessing outer scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

So I've got this JS code here, and I'm trying to set obj from the success and error callbacks, but apparently the `toLinkInfo` function scope is not a parent scope of those? I always get null back from this function no matter what. I tried a bunch of stuff but couldn't get it to work, I guess I'm too used to C & friends :) How can I get this to work?

```
LinkInfoGrabber.prototype.toLinkInfo = function() {
    var obj = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: this.getRequestUrl(),
        success: function(raw) {
            obj = new LinkInfo(raw);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            obj = new LinkInfoException(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });

    if (obj instanceof LinkInfo) {
        return obj;
    } else {
        throw obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the condition is not being met

Comment: I've seen this question a couple times already.

Comment: My thinking cap is not working at the moment. Could you add the LinkInfo constructor as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because AJAX calls are asynchronous -- they happen at a different time from the rest of the context.

Try giving it a callback function( called callback below ).

```
LinkInfoGrabber.prototype.toLinkInfo = function(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.getRequestUrl(),
        success: function(raw) {
            callback( new LinkInfo(raw) );
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            obj = new LinkInfoException(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}

var l = new LinkInfoGrabber()
l.toLinkInfo(console.log) //replace console.log with something meaningful
```

While this approach does not provide exactly the same result as being able to call everything inline, it has the benefit of allowing for the asynchronous nature of the web.

Comment: How hilarious of me to actually forget that **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML is asynchronous. I ended up moving the $.ajax call outside that function instead and that works nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
if (obj instanceof LinkInfo) {
        return obj;
    } else {
        throw obj;
    }
```

runs immediately after you START the ajax call, but obj is not set until the ajax call finishes successfully.  This is a common misunderstanding.  The Ajax call is asynchronous.  Your call to $.ajax() starts the asynchronous call and then the rest of your function immediately executes.  The success handler is called only when the ajax call succeeds (some time later).  You can't return obj from your function.  You have to handle obj in your success handler and then call anything further that wants to use it from the success handler.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `obj` before the call to `ajax` returns, so it's not set to anything but null when it is returned.