# How do i return value in this example?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function nicktoid(nick){
    if (typeof nick == "String") {
    var u = "http://xxxxxx.xxxx/" + nick ;
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.open('GET',u, true);
    xhr2.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    xhr2.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');

    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr2.readyState == 4)  {
        txt2 = xhr2.responseText;
        var el2 = document.createElement("div");
        el2.innerHTML = txt2;

        anchors = el2.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i=0;i< anchors.length;i++){
            if (anchors[i].parentNode.id == "profile_avatar"){

                anc.push(anchors[i]);
            }


        }

        var res = anc[0].href;
        var arstr = res.split("_");
        var resul = arstr[0].substr(6);

}

}



}
}
```

i have the above code. What is right way to return `var resul` to nicktoid routine??

Comment: I would learn how JavaScript operators work first: [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing outer scope in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673712/accessing-outer-scope-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback function, since the Ajax request executes asynchronously

```
function nicktoid(nick, callback){
    ...
    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        ...
        callback && callback(resul);
    }
}

nicktoid('foobar', function(resul) {
    console.log(resul);
});
```

Comment: does this code return resul?? i mean, can i use  var x =  nicktoid('foobar', function(resul) {
    console.log(resul);
}); ??

Comment: No, the function cannot return a result since it is executing an asynchronous Ajax request. You have to refactor your code to support this asynchronous nature, i.e. place your return value processing inside that function.

Comment: i see, thanks! but why do you use boolean operator in this example??

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have explained that. It ensures that the callback is only executed if it has actually been defined, allowing you to still use the function without passing a callback. Maybe not useful in this instance but definitely good as a general practice.

Answer (score 2):

ajax in general is asynchronous.

So you cannot return -- you **must** use callbacks.

---

So you can do `nextFuntion(resul);` and parse your information there.

Comment: Adding onto Neal's answer, you could pass nextFunction into nicktoid.  the definition would look like this: function nicktoid(nick, nextFunction){}.  Later, the call would look like this: nicktoid("whatever", function(resul){ /* use resul here */ });

Comment: how do i use callbacks in this example??